# Do I have partial view/code behind in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm migrating from C#.NET to Python/Flask.

In .NET I have `MasterPage, UserControl, PartialView` each has its own code behind.

e.g. I can save the check login functions in `Login.ascx.cs` and render the `Login.ascx` wherever I'd like to. If logged in, it shows the welcome message, else shows the login form.

But in Flask I only found `{% include 'login.html' %}` which include the static html file.

How can I implement this design in Flask?

**I May Have the Answer Now:**

I'm not using `g.user` and that's why I came here for help. Someone else suggested `@app.context_processor`. I'm trying that and it seems like what I want. The similar global accessible design as `g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spite of what its name might make you think it does [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) does not insert the contents of static HTML files.  It actually inserts the contents of *rendered* Jinja templates and it functions very much like a partial view from MVC (if I understand them correctly).  It [has access to the parent template context](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#import-context-behavior) by default.  So if, for example, you are storing the user on `g.user`, since `g` is accessible by default you can simply do this:

```
<-- login.html -->
{% if g.user.is_anonymous() %}
Login form goes here
{% else %}
Greetings {{g.user.full_name}}!
{% endif %}
```

And `{% include "login.html" %}` wherever you want the login form / user greeting to show up.

**Response to edit**

If you want to make sure that `user` is accessible to all templates you can indeed use [`context_processor`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors) to add a `user`:

```
@app.context_processor
def add_user():
    # Get user
    return {"user": user}
```

Comment: I'm not using `g.user` and that's why I came here for help. Someone  else suggested `@app.context_processor`. I'm trying that and it seems like what I want. The similar `global accessible` design as `g`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Flask-Login](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Login/), which is an extension of Flask. After configuring it, you can achieve your requirements.